# RandomAccessFile on internal storage

Tags: android

I would like to save a file on my internal storage and then after some processing to open it with RandomAccessFile,  when I try to open the file it throws an exception FileNotFound...
where did i go wrong?

`FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("xxx.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

`RandomAccessFile access = new RandomAccessFile("xxx.txt", "r");`

Comment: are you sure that the file exists?

Comment: I think you should check your file path or should check file is exist on the path on which you are checking

Answer (score 2):

If you create a file and write to it, you have to close() it before re-opening.

In addition, at least on some devices the file by default goes to the root directory.

```
public void test() {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile access = new RandomAccessFile(new File(getFilesDir(),"xxx.txt"), "rw");
        access.writeBytes("hello");
        access.close();
    } catch (IOException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: fos.close() doesnt helped, still 
F

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because you wrote to a file through:

```
FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("xxx.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

but then you try to open a file at the default directory:

```
RandomAccessFile access = new RandomAccessFile("xxx.txt", "r");
```

which is different than the output directory used previously.

**Therefore**, you can obtain the directory used by `openFileOutput()` with `getFileStreamPath (String name)`, so create your `RandomAccessFile` with this:

```
RandomAccessFile access = new RandomAccessFile(getFileStreamPath("xxx.txt"), "r");
```